# regex to fetch string between [a] and [/a] excluding any other tag like [b][/b] that comes in between

Tags: c#, regex

I have an input like the following

```
[a href=http://twitter.com/suddentwilight][font][b][i]@suddentwilight[/font][/a] My POV: Rakhi Sawant hits below the belt &amp; does anything for attention... [a href=http://twitter.com/mallikaLA][b]http://www.test.com[/b][/a] has maintained the grace/decency :)
```

Now I need to get the string `@suddentwilight` and `http://www.test.com` that comes inside the anchor tags. there might be some [b] or [i] like tags wrapping the actual text. I need to ignore that.

Basically I need to get a string matching that starts with `[a]` then need to get the string/url before closing of the a tag `[/a]`.

Please Suggest

Answer (score 3):

I don't know C#, but here's a regex:

```
/\[a\s+[^\]]*\](?:\[[^\]]+\])*(.*?)(?:\[[^\]]+\])*\[\/a\]/
```

This will match `[a ...][tag1][tag2][...][tagN]text[/tagN]...[tag2][tag1][/a]` and capture `text`.

To explain:

- the `/.../` are common regex delimiters (like double quotes for strings).  C# may just use strings to initialize regexes - in which case the forward slashes aren't necessary.
- `\[` and `\]` match a literal `[` and `]` character.  We need to escape them with a backslash since square brackets have a special meaning in regexes.
- `[^\]]` is an example of a character class - here meaning any character that is not a close square bracket.  The square brackets delimit the character class, the caret (`^`) denotes negation, and the escaped close square bracket is the character being negated.
- `*` and `+` are suffixes meaning match 0 or more and 1 or more of the previous pattern, respectively.  So `[^\]]*` means match 0 or more of anything except a close square bracket.
- `\s` is a shorthand for the character class of whitespace characters
- `(?:...)` allows you to group the contents into an atomic pattern.
- `(...)` groups like `(?:...)` does, but also saves the substring that this portion of the regex matches into a variable.  This is normally called a *capture*, since it captures this portion of the string for you to use later.  Here, we are using a capture to grab the linktext.
- `.` matches any single character.
- `*?` is a suffix for non-greedy matching.  Normally, the `*` suffix is greedy, and matches as much as it can while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match something.   `*?` is the opposite - it matches as little as it can while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match something.  The reason we use `*?` here instead of `*` is so that if we have multiple `[/a]`s on a line, we only go as far as the next one when matching link text.

This will only remove `[tag]`s that come at the beginning and end of the text, to remove any that come in the middle of the text (like `[a href=""]a [b]big[/b] frog[/a]`), you'll need to do a second pass on the capture from the first, scrubbing out any text that matches:

```
/\[[^\]]+\]/
```

Comment: Nope this expression dosent seems to be working for me :(. It returns empty string as output.

Comment: Which method are you using the regex with?  One that requires that the regex match the entire string, or one that requires that the regex only match a substring?  C# has both.

Comment: i am using:

var output = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

Comment: ok now here is the diffrence: 

When i put forward slashes / in pattern it returns empty string but pattern without forward slashes returns [a href=twitter.com/suddentwilight][font][b][i]@suddentwilight[/font][/a] however i just want @suddentwilight from the output. I want to exlcude the string we are using to match the pattern.

Comment: Like I said above - try removing the `/` delimiters - C# doesn't use them.  The text should be in `output.Captures(1)` on success.

Comment: See here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx for example on getting the captured text out of a match.